# Show Changed But Undeployed Files in VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I'm working on a Lightning App site where I'm developing locally using Visual Studio Code, and then deploying my changes to my default org (I'm using the Salesforce CLI Integration extension).

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to show which files I've made updates to but have not deployed to my default org?

I noticed that a change I made was not visible on the website, and then I realized "oh!" I never deployed the change. And then I started getting suspicious and wondering what other changes have I not deployed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [diff against the org](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/source-diff/) commands for a UI that shows changes from your org (in both directions!).

You can also see your current status from a terminal command:

```
sfdx force:source:status
```

Or you can deploy any changes that are detected in your workspace:

```
sfdx force:source:push
```

You can also go in to your Settings (File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > Salesforce Feature Previews > Salesforcedx-vscode-core > Push or Deploy On Save) to make sure that every file you save automatically pushes.

Comment: also worth mentioning [diff against the org](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/source-diff/) as a useful sanity check

Comment: @KrisGoncalves historically, that command has never worked for me, so I forgot about it. I'll edit that in.

Comment: "...to make sure that every file you save automatically pushes." That scares me.

Comment: @Moonpie To each their own; I personally prefer to know that what is on my screen is what's in the org (but I'm also a "master" developer with lots of confidence and a bit of hubris), but you can at least take comfort that if there's any compilation errors on push, nothing will be modified on the server until everything is fixed; your server should never be in a wholly inoperable state.

Comment: Touché! I am closer to a "junior" developer with lots of confidence and lots of hubris.

Answer (score 3):

- Use `sfdx force:source:push` rather than `...:deploy`
- Use `sfdx force:source:pull` rather than `...:retrieve`

Then you can use `sfdx force:source:status` to see changes.

- If you are using a Scratch Org, you should just be able to use the above commands.
- If you are using a Sandbox, in your Dev Hub org you will need to go to *Setup >> Dev Hub* and check **Enable Source Tracking** in order to be able to use the above commands.

To start off with a "clean slate" so to speak, when you first set this up in your Sandbox, and you have already done some work like you have, you can run

- `sfdx force:source:tracking:clear` to clear local tracking
- `sfdx force:source:tracking:reset` to clear both local and remote tracking

*See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_tracking.htm*